# NSXMLParser works not correct with symbols like â€œ

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser, symbols

I have some problems with parsing of xml in my iPhone Application. Here is some part of xml code that I want to parse with standard `NSXMLParser` parser.

```
<item>
<title>AMNews: Facebook & Twitter Updates Might Lead To Burglary, Oldham School Violates DPA, Amazon Cloud â€œBurstsâ€</title>
<link>http://www.itproportal.com/2011/04/22/amnews-facebook-twitter-updates-might-lead-to-burglary-oldham-school-violates-dpa-amazon-cloud-bursts/</link>
<description>People announcing their holiday plans on social networking platforms like Facebook and Twitter are putting themselves at risks from thieves and burglars. A new study ha</description>
<author>ravimandalia@itproportal.com (Ravi Mandalia)</author>
<pubDate>Fri, 22 Apr 2011 08:19:36 +0100</pubDate>
<guid>http://cdn.itproportal.com/photos/facebook-logo-4_thumb80x80.png</guid>
</item>
```

How you can see in

```
<title>AMNews: Facebook & Twitter Updates Might Lead To Burglary, Oldham School Violates DPA, Amazon Cloud â€œBurstsâ€</title>
```

title tag some strange symbols appear "**â€œ**" "**â**". In function

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
```

I am trying to get title and save it, but my parser works wrong. Parser take only text after "**â€œ**" symbol !!!

What can I do and can anybody tell me what happens with parse ? Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is implementation of `-parser:foundCharacters:`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    //in case of unusable tags
    if (currentArticle == nil) {
        return;
    }
    // Get Title.   
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [self.currentArticle setTheTitle:string];
    // Get Description.
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @"" ];
        [self.currentArticle setTheSummary:string];

    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [self.currentArticle setTheMainLink:string];

    } else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"guid"]){
        [self.currentArticle setTheImageLink:string];

    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [self.currentArticle setThePubDate:string];

    } else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"author"]){
        [self.currentArticle  setTheAuthor:string];
    }
}
```

I have notice  that parser get title two times at first time from the begin to the â€œ and second time from â€œ to end. Like in my feed there are two **title** tags.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us your implementation of `-parser:foundCharacters:`? How do you store `string`?

I have also once used an `NSXMLParser` with special characters in the XML file, and it worked without problems.